# How to have ingest time - processing time as a field in elastic transform

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-transform

I have a pivot transform in elastic that groups data and then performs some arbitrary aggregations on it. The transform frequency is 10 minutes, which means it runs every 10 minutes.
Processing of the data takes longer based on the load on the machine and I want to see how long it took to process the data after it runs. For example if the transform starts running at minute X maybe it takes 2 minutes to run so X+2 is the time i see aggregated data. What i want to see in the transform is this X+2 or X+n to be general as a field.

I couldn't get transform to have a field that doesn't use aggregations because of this I never got the chance to get to timestamp part of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to [find the stats](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/get-transform-stats.html) of the latest transform with the following query:

```
GET _transform/<transform_id>/_stats
```

Comment: Great this shows what I wanted but can I extract the value timestamp_millis and add it to my transform documents?

Comment: I don't think so because this document is obviously updated **after** the transform has finished running. You can probably do it manually using an update by query, though.